# WordPress: How to load Bootstrap Modal content on-click from template-parts?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, bootstrap-4

In my WordPress, I am using Bootstrap 4. I have the below button to show a modal.

```
<button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-text">Show Text Modal</button>
```

Below Modal text content is in a separate `template-parts/modal-text.php` file.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-text" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-text-label" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">    
         TEXT here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have several of these modals in a single page; so using this [guide](http://chasewiseman.com/modals-for-wordpress-themes-using-ajax-template-parts/), I wanted to load a particular modal content from `template-parts` only when clicking on a button.

As per the guide, below is the AJAX request:

```
$(function () {
    var loadModal = function (modal) {
        $.post(
                theme_modals.ajax_url,
                {
                    action: 'load_modal',
                    modal: modal
                },
                /* Handle the response! */
                        function (response) {
                            if (0 !== response) {
                                modal = $.parseHTML(response);
                                /* Add the modal to the body. */
                                $('body').append(modal);
                                /* Take various actions when the modal is added. */
                                $(modal).addClass('modal-show');
                                $('body').addClass('has-modal');
                            }
                        }
                );
            };
});
```

And, below is the function to prevent default Modal on-click function and load the specific Modal content

```
$('[data-modal]').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var modal = $(this).data('modal');
    loadModal(modal);
});
```

Below the function to load the requested Modal via AJAX:

```
function theme_ajax_load_modal() {
    ob_start();
    get_template_part('template-parts/modal', $_POST['modal']);
    $modal = ob_get_clean();
    if ($modal) {
        echo $modal;
    } else {
        echo 0;
    }
    die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_load_modal', 'theme_ajax_load_modal');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_modal', 'theme_ajax_load_modal');
```

Modal is not showing on button click, by using the above functions. 
However, able to show Modal using the default `<?php get_template_part('template-parts/modal', 'text'); ?>`.

How can I make this code work to load specific content from `template-parts` only when I click the related button.

Comment: You attach click event to to `$('[data-modal]')` but the element does not exist in your code.

Comment: I tried `$('.btn').on('click', function (e) {`, still did not worked.

Comment: is Ajax call being fired on button click? You can check it in the developer console, under network tab -> XHR.

Comment: Under XHR, it is blank table.